# xargs inside a for loop

Tags: linux, kill, xargs

So we got most of it figured out but here's what happens.

```
for i in $(arp |sort |awk '{print $1}'|grep IPADDRESS)
do
ssh USERNAME@$i "ps -ef |grep X11|grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill"
done

kill: USERNAME: invalid process id
```

I've SSH'd using the username I'm using for the loop and ran `ps -ef | grep X11| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill` just fine but it looks like xargs is picking up the username instead of whats being printed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try a `\` in front of `$` in awk.  example:

`ssh USERNAME@$i "ps -ef |grep X11|grep -v grep |awk '{print \$2}'|xargs kill"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use pkill instead, no need so many pipes

```
ssh USERNAME@$i "pkill -f X11"
```

or if you prefer ps -ef,

```
ssh USERNAME@$i "ps -ef |grep [X]11 |awk '{print \$2}'|xargs kill"
```

or

```
ssh USERNAME@$i "ps -ef | awk '/[X]11/ {print \$2}'|xargs kill"
```